# Sometimes Python Requests module and wget HTTP responses contradicts curl/Chrome

Tags: http, python-2.7, python-requests

On checking HTTP status code returns on a bunch on URLs I occasionally see disparities between the results from the Python 'requests' module and linux curl.

This URL http://www.dagoradiosound.info/site/ returns '404' with 'requests' and wget but '200' with curl and the chrome browser.

Does anyone know why I am getting these contradictory results?

```
#Python
import requests
url = "http://www.dagoradiosound.info/site/"
r = requests.head(url)
r.status_code

#curl
curl -sL -w "%{http_code} %{url_effective}\\n" "http://www.dagoradiosound.info/site/" -o /dev/null

#wget
wget --spider "http://www.dagoradiosound.info/site/"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're sending a HEAD request with `requests` rather than a GET.
Try `requests.get("http://www.dagoradiosound.info/site/")` instead.

Using `curl -I "http://www.dagoradiosound.info/site/"` to fetch the headers only will also return a 404 status for this particular URL.